Gradle error google services error in android studio java
I am building android studio project and gradle was running properly but when I add the plugin
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

it start giving me the following 2 errors

Unable to find method ''void com.android.build.api.variant.ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtension.registerSourceType(java.lang.String)''
'void com.android.build.api.variant.ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtension.registerSourceType(java.lang.String)'

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

And

'void com.android.build.api.variant.ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtension.registerSourceType(java.lang.String)'

I had tried to resolve this by adding dependencies. Now my build.gradle file code is below:
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'  // Use the latest version
        // Use the latest version
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'  // Use the desired version


    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.1' apply false
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

and build.gradle module file code is:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myproject"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.6'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    implementation 'nl.psdcompany:duo-navigation-drawer:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1'
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.1")
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
}

I want help on why I am getting error agter adding that plugin and how to resolve that?

this is gradle compatibility issue,,, is eaither you update your gradle or use a lower version of the plugin that is compatible with your gradle version

try https://developer.android.com/build/agp-upgrade-assistant

also can you share your gradle build wrapper

One of the lines you shared states: Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

I resolved my issue by upgrading the Android Gradle plugin. Initially, the updates didn't seem to be available, possibly due to using an older version of Android Studio. However, upon updating Android Studio to the latest version, I received a prompt to update the Gradle plugin, which ultimately resolved the problem
